# Guaranteed method of stripping leading/trailing spaces from form input

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to ensure that all leading and trailing spaces are removed from a form. The issue arose as a user entered an email address with a space and when they attempted to log in with this email address it wasnt accepted. I understand there are ways to do this via the server side but was looking a quick fix. I therefore used this piece of code:

```
$("input").change(function()
{
    this.value=$(this).val().trim();
});
```

I want to know if anyone can see an instance where this will not work, such as a person filling an input and hitting enter rather than tabbing to or clicking the next input.

Comment: What if some user has js disabled? Ensure that the server side script can handle in case of failure on the part of frontend.

Comment: It's much better to just do it server side. Don't rely on client-side JS for proper validation of data if it goes into your application logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim the input on form submit.

```js
  
   $('input').blur(function(){
       this.value=$(this).val().trim();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text"><br><br>
  <input type="text"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this and the functionality doesnt seem to fit what I am attempting to do. If you click on your input box type a few characters and then a few spaces, tab out and back the spaces remain.

Comment: How about the now?

Comment: Still no. If I enter "ddddddddddd         " and either tab or click the other input I come back and the input still contains "ddddddddddd         ". Are you getting the same result?

Comment: This will trim all the leading\trailing space when you submit your form to login. If this is not what you want. What are the test cases?

Comment: What I want is to strip it when the user tabs or clicks away from the form element.

Comment: then try with the `blur` event

Comment: Weird. It works for all inputs except the email input I need it to work for. I'm not sure why but will mark you answer as correct. Apologies for the run around.